# Zebra IMZ 320 printing image takes too long (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, printing, zebra-printers

I am using Zebra IMZ 320 to print pdf document from iOS (receipt actually) and it works. But i takes about 50 seconds to print a 23 kb pdf document.

I was thinking maybe if i send it in a hexadecimal format that the printer would understand, printing time would decrease but i can't find how to send it in byte format. I tried to look zpl codes but from my understanding it is mostly about converting an image to .grf format and send it to printer using utilities but my images are dynamic.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Here is my code to send print images :

```
CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)pdfData);
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(dataProvider);

    size_t nPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(document);
    size_t pageNum;
    for (pageNum = 1; pageNum <= nPages; pageNum++) {

        UIImage* image = nil;

        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, pageNum);

        CGRect rect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFArtBox);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, YES, 2.6);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGColorSpaceRef rgb = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
        const CGFloat fillColors[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};

        CGColorRef colorRef = CGColorCreate(rgb, fillColors);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, colorRef);
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(rgb);
        CGColorRelease(colorRef);

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, rect.size.height);

        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        if (page != NULL)
        {
            CGContextSaveGState(context);

            CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFCropBox, rect, 0, true);

            CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);

            CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

            CGContextRestoreGState(context);

            image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        }

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if (nil != image) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            success = [graphicsUtil printImage:[image CGImage] atX:0 atY:0 withWidth:x withHeight:y
                             andIsInsideFormat:NO error:&error];
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Note : Yes this is over bluetooth

Comment: is this over bluetooth?

Comment: How long does it take to render the PDF? How big is the pdf before you make the call to send the bytes to the printer?  Bluetooth is a lot slower than TCP, so it takes a while if the image is big

Comment: PDF is 23 kb and it takes 50 seconds to print it from imz320 but it also takes 50 seconds to print 100 kb pdf too. From my observations printing image time is about how long the paper because i once print a empty pdf 20 cm longs, and it also took lots of time

Answer (score 0):

One way to reduce the time is to send the text of the receipt to the printer (formatted in the printer language) instead of sending the PDF image; this approach would drastically reduce the number of bytes that have to be sent over Bluetooth, typically to under 1K.

Comment: I take it the OP was aware of that and asking how this could be done using the available SDKs? So what's probably needed is suggestions for sending ZPL, CPCL or EPL to said zebra printer in objective-C. Maybe [this library](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) or [these](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/03/sending-raw-epl2-directly-to-a-zebra-lp2844-via-c/) [resources](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=WH35&actp=LIST_POPULAR) are useful.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i was asking, btw we reduced the printing time to half by using ZPL printing language instead of CPL